# es6 import gives undefined on named export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this simple import:

```
import {reducers as sharedStore} from "./components/shared";
```

and have this exports on the index.js file located in side the

```
./components/shared
```

folders.

this is index.js content:

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
export const reducers = combineReducers({selectAssetView, video:videoReducerComp });
```

Comment: and `sharedStore` is `undefined`?

Comment: what build tool are you using?

Comment: Do you potentially have circular dependencies in your modules? Hard to tell with the code you've posted.

Comment: @Amir it is undefined.

Comment: @maioman Im using webpack.

Comment: @loganfsmyth this is a new project I got in to so there a lot of deps inside it, if there is something that depends on something that depends on that something it may create that?

Comment: Is there a file named `shared.js` under `./components`? do other modules resolve successfully?

Comment: id recommend you try two things first: 1) do - import {reducers as sharedStore} from "./components/shared/index"; 2) try defining reducers in your index.js first and then doing export { reducers};